# How to split string using Regex.Split()

Tags: c#, regex, split, pattern-matching

I have one string separated by colons (`:`) as follows:

```
string str = @"E:\C_Sharp\Projects\Split\test.xlsx:03/08/2016
09:12:56:file name 1,demo1.txt,date create,01/07/2016 09:12:file name
2,demo2.txt,date create,12/07/2016 14:05";
```

Now I want to split into 4 substring as below:

```
str1 = @"E:\C_Sharp\Projects\Split\test.xlsx";
str2 = "03/08/2016 09:12:56"
str3 = "file name 1,demo1.txt,date create,01/07/2016 09:12"
str4 = "file name 2,demo2.txt,date create,12/07/2016 14:05"
```

I used pattern `string pattern = @"\D:\D";` but it can't.

Comment: When exactly should the string be splitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your pattern is incorrect. Based on string you've provided, it should be `\D:\d|\d:\D`, i.e. you want to find occurences of colon surrounded by digit from one side and non-digit from another side.

Second problem is that `Regex.Split` will remove all occurences of search pattern, so characters around colons at delimiter places will be lost. You can avoid it by replacing delimiter patterns to some character which will never occur in your string and then split by this character.

So you can extract your values like:

```
string str = @"E:\C_Sharp\Projects\Split\test.xlsx:03/08/2016 09:12:56:file name 1,demo1.txt,date create,01/07/2016 09:12:file name 2,demo2.txt,date create,12/07/2016 14:05";

var values = Regex.Replace(str, @"\D:\d|\d:\D", m => m.Groups[0].Value.Replace(":", "\0"))
                  .Split('\0');
```

Comment: I have understood. Thank you!

Comment: string str1 = @"E:\C_Sharp\Projects\Split\test.xlsx:03/08/2016 09:12:56:file name 1,demo1.txt,date create 1,01/07/2016 09:12,author1,:file name 2,demo2.txt,date create 2,12/07/2016 14:05,author2,petter c:\england:file name 3,demo3.txt,date create 3,19/09/2009 19:09,,"; <------> var values1 = Regex.Replace(str1, @"\D:\d|\d:\D|\D:\D", m => m.Groups[0].Value.Replace(":", "\0")) .Split('\0'); <------> => incorrect results, Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: @MinhKiyo well, if your problem is  in `author1,:file name 2` part of the string as I can suppose, you can try to handle this case by the use of regex pattern like `[\D,]:\d|[\d,]:\D`.

Comment: AndyKorneyev, thank you! I tried to handle with regex pattern `[\D,]:\d|[\d,]:\D` , but it can't. Image of result: http://i1177.photobucket.com/albums/x356/kiyo2913/SplitString_zpsnz88yahn.png . Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MinhKiyo surely it won't split, since this case (letters from both sides of colon) was never mentioned by you. Well, it brings us back to `\D:\D` pattern you've tried to use, but it will split too much, for example it will split "e:\"  So you need to exclude slashes and other possible unwanted charactes, say like  `\D:\d|\d:\D|[^\d^\\]:[^d^\\]`. Here is essential last part - "everythig except digit or backslash, then colon and again everythig except digit or backslash". If it still will not met some of your edge cases... well, tune it up. ;)

Comment: AndyKorneyev! Thank you for your detailed explanation to help me! I learned a lot things from you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest replacing the colons with a better delimiter, then splitting on that.

To replace only the colons that should be split on, you can use this regex:

```
(?<=\d\d):(?=\D)|(?<=\D):(?=\d\d)
```

Use some character you know will not appear elsewhere in the string. Then, you just need to split on that character.

It's a little bit fragile, since it may break if the filename is `1filename`, but this is dependent on your situation.

---

The regex uses positive look-arounds: `(?<=)` is to look behind, `(?=)` is to look ahead.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

You got really tricky case, but here what can i sugges:

1. Add `:` symbol at the begin and at the end of your line
2. Use this regex to find all matches `(?!<=[0-9]:)(?<=:).+?(?=:)(?!:([0-9]|\\))`

I [create an example](https://regex101.com/r/rF7fK5/1) to show that it really works.

Note `(?!:([0-9]|\\))` part. I add `\` symbol to match your folder path right way.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!